# Execute stored procedure using xml file

Tags: sql-server, xml, visual-studio-2010, ssis

I have a db in SQL Server with some tables and stored procedures. And I created an ssis packpage in visual studio. I want the package run the stored procedure, but specify the parameters, source and destination tables through an XML configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to modify the stored procedure to use dynamic SQL. You will need to add additional parameters in the Stored Procedure to accept the table names.

In the SSIS package, add an XML Task with an XPath operation to read the nodes into SSIS variables. You can then pass the SSIS variables into the execute SQL task. Make sure you also set delay validation on this task